# ¿De qué manera puedo hacer botones dinámicos sin tener que escribir todos y cada uno de ellos?

Tags: android

Quisiera saber si existe alguna manera en android para hacer un arreglo de botones o algo así.

Lo que tengo en mente es un `scrollView` lleno de botones (20 - 30) pero sin tener que poner en el xml cada botón. Existe alguna forma de hacer eso des de java y sin tener que escribir `Button` 1,2,3,...etc.?

EDITADO

Ya me funcionó, muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Código Java:

```
LinearLayout layout,contenedorBoton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        contenedorBoton = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
        ImageView btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.boton);
        contenedorBoton.setTag(i);

        contenedorBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Listener botón " + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        layout.addView(contenedorBoton);
    }
```

Código XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/boton"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que deseas es generar dinamicamente botones dentro de una vista, por ejemplo lo que muestro en esta imagen :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes realizarlo generando instancias del botón y agregarlos a tu layout, este es un ejemplo para crear botones custom, revisa lo que realiza dentro del `for`:

```
  LinearLayout btnsContainer = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    btnsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btnsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    btnsContainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //Crea botons dinamicamente.
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        final LinearLayout buttonContainer = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_button,null);
        ImageView btnImg = (ImageView) buttonContainer.findViewById(R.id.btn_image);
        TextView btnTxt = (TextView) buttonContainer.findViewById(R.id.btn_text);
        btnTxt.setText("mi Botón no." +  i);
        btnTxt.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
        btnImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        buttonContainer.setTag(i);

        buttonContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Listener botón " + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        //Va agregegando botones al contenedor.
        btnsContainer.addView(buttonContainer);
    }
    //Crea contenedor para agregar contenedor de botones.
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, 1500, Gravity.CENTER);
    //Agrega contenedor con botones.
    addContentView(btnsContainer, params);
```

Este sería el layout del botón usado en el ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10px"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#F0F0F0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Si desearas unicamente botones no personalizados el procedimiento es similar creando instancias de Button:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mi_linear_layout);

        LinearLayout contenedor = new LinearLayout(this);
       contenedor.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++ {
            Button boton = new Button(this);
            boton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            boton.setText("mi Botón " + i);
            boton.setId(i);
            contenedor.addView(boton);
        }
    
layout.addView(contenedor);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por ese ejemplo me sirve mucho, una duda mas, como le hago para meter esos botones en un horizontalSrcollView?

Comment: En el ejemplo se agregan los botones a un LinearLayout que es btnsContainer, lo que tienes que hacer es agregar este Layout al HorizontalScrollView:
scrollView.addView(btnsContainer); trata de hacerlo y si tienes duda pregunta nuevamente.

Comment: Hola, ya lo intenté de esa forma pero me muestra un error, así lo puse  HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);        ScrollView.addView(btnsContainer);        y el error que me muestra es el siguiente  "HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child"

Comment: Erick pero que error obtienes? da más detalles.

Comment: me saca de la app, el error lo marca en la line de código  "scrollView.addView(btnsContainer)"       java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child.

Comment: Ahhhhh el scrollView unicamente debe tener una vista, si son varias agregalas en un solo contenedor y ese agregalo al scrollview

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, pero me podrias explicar para que un LinearLayout al momento de crear los botones dinámicos?, no se puede hacer algo como Buttons[] botones = new Buttons[20];

Comment: Puede ser cualquier vista, es como ejemplo ya que necesitas un contenedor para agregar tus botones.

Comment: Ojalá todos pudieran escribir respuestas de esta forma

Comment: Erik Deberías de marcar la respuesta de @Elenasys como correcta y postear otra pregunta para tus futuros problemas ya que eso soluciona tu problema original, saludos.